# Formating of URL in webbrowser doesn't work

Tags: python

Chrome says it can not find the url.

Yet, When I run the program the URL prints out as:
'https://www.gettyimages.com/detail/photo/london-tower-bridge-river-thames-city-skyscrapers-royalty-free-image/860119662?adppopup=true'

If I replace the variable "url" with the actual url above in the webbrowser.open it finds the webpage  perfectly.

Here is the actual code:

```
# Reading an excel file using Python
import xlrd

# Give the location of the file
loc = ('F:\\Documents\\Fun Stuff\\Other\\bridges.xlsx')

# To open Workbook
book = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)

# input is requested and stored in a variable
row_text = input('Row Number =  ')
# convert user input into an integer
row_number = int(row_text)

# For row “row_number” and column 2
cell_value = sheet.cell(row_number, 1)
url = str(cell_value)
url = url[5:]

#Verify url is extracted from Excel sheet
print(url)

# open-webpage
import webbrowser

#Path to webbrower
chrome_path = ('C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s')

# open-webpage
webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open(url, new=0)
```

Comment: Is there any white space?

Comment: Try `print(repr(url))` and see if it appears differently.

Comment: That was the answer.  When I printed using the print(repr(url) I found it had an extra set of quotes.  Replaced the url = url[5:] with url[6:-1].  Now it works perfectly.